# HTML justify content and span

Tags: html

```css
.d1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.s1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <u>list:</u>
    <br>item1
    <br>item2
    <br><span class="s1">item3</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to make a div where its contents are aligned in the center. I use the above code to display the text `list: item1 item2 item3` one below the other, `list:` underlined and the `item3` to have blue color but this gives so strange results:

[image]

`item1` and `item2` but `item3` is... on top and next to `list:`... What's the matter and how can I fix this? Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by not using `flex` but `inline-block` and a wrapper `<div>` instead.

```css
.d1 {
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
.d2 {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
.s1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <div class="d2">
        <u>list:</u>
        <br>item1
        <br>item2
        <br><span class="s1">item3</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<li>` along with `<u>` and add `u li {list-style-type: none;}` to disable list item circle.

Check this  :

```css
.d1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.s1 {
    color: blue;
}
u li {list-style-type: none;}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <u>list:
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item2</li>
     <li><span class="s1">item3</span></li>
    </u>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.d1 {
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.s1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
    <u>list:</u>
    <br>item1
    <br>item2
    <br><span class="s1">item3</span>
</div>
```

Result okay?

Answer (score 1):

You could make you usage of an unsorted list like this one here: 
If you need a more specific solution let me know that!

```css
.d1 {
    background-color: red;
    justify-content: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center
}
.s1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
<p>Items:</p>
<lu>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li><span class="s1">item3</span></li>
 </lu>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why you used `<u>` tag and "display:flex". If you use `display:flex` then its child nodes will take the whole height and `<u>list:</u>`, `<span class="s1">item3</span>` have done that and created 3 column. besides other content are not considered as the child nodes.
You can see the [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flex) to clear the idea of flex